# IMS database from a .NET program

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, zos, cics, ims-db

i am using this **cac101wn.exe** driver downloaded from [here](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/data/integration/iicf/)
 to access **Mainframe IMS** database from my .net application. 
i had gone through this [article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iisclzos/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.prod.fed.classic.nav.doc/topics/iiyfcnavcf.html). 
i was able to read IMS DB and i was so happy.
 When i propose an idea based on this, architect disapprove ,
cause we are using IMS DB for Financial transaction. 
Below is what architect suggested to me.

Mainframe team can stand up a **Synchrnonsout CICS WebService** that
 can be called directly by Your C#.net application.
 The CICS WS will handle any transaction integrity issues and roll 
back problem transaction initiated by Your Application.

Now i really want to know that

1.what is wrong in this approach?

2.Does anyone have ever use Classic Federation Server and let me
know what is the pros and cons of it?

Thanks in advance

Please let me know if the question is vague and further clarification is required

---

Comment: Hi Sanatnu, I'm a software engineer with IMS. Can you please provide some more information about your environment so that we can do a better job answer your questions. What version of IMS are you using? Also, do you have the IMS TM or just IMS DB?

Comment: IMS version 7 and just IMS DB @JustinDanielson.

Comment: Ask your question here: http://imslistserv.bmc.com/scripts/wa-BMC.exe?A0=IMS-L or http://ibmmainframeforum.com/viewforum.php?f=23 they would definitely be able to provide you a thorough answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach suggested by your architect seems sound to me. He is possibly concerned that rogue versions of the client end of the application (or clever tools that access the database directly) could be subverted to perform the updates in unauthorised manner - a common concern with client-server applications. Managing the distribution and synchronised use of updates is also a challenge as the number of clients increases.

Creating a CICS web service that you can call is pretty simple - assuming that you have a suitable program available that encapsulates the functions that you need, and that you have CICS installed, of course. Web services have been available in CICS to some extent since V2.3. Which release are you on?

Another option would be to use the Microsoft .Net APIs in CICS Transaction Gateway to drive your CICS program directly.

Architects are there for a reason - they stop buildings falling down and injuring the inhabitants. I suggest that you listen to yours.

Regards, John

Answer (score 4):

IMS 7 has been out of support for several years.  IMS 13 is the current version of IMS and it has native support for .NET applications to access IMS DB.  More information can be found at www.ibm.com/ims